# Qual a ordem de processamento de um script PHP?

Tags: php

#### Cenário exemplo:

```
echo hello();
echo '<br>';
echo 'Hello ' . world('World');

function hello() {

    return 'World';
}

function world($v) {

    return $v;  
}
```

Saída:

```
World
Hello World
```

---

#### Como o `PHP` processa isso?

**Sobre o exemplo, podemos concluir:** o `echo` está antes do **método**, então o **PHP não lê linha por linha na sequencialmente**, pois caso fosse dessa forma, ele não teria lido o **método** mais abaixo para poder resolver a linha atual (que está antes), correto!?

#### Dúvidas:

- Ele vem lendo **linha por linha** e ao posicionar em uma linha que chama um método, ele **busca aquele método em todo script** e **armazena na memória**, e só depois **volta para resolver** onde parou?

  - Supondo ser dessa forma, ao terminar de buscar o método e resolver a linha em posição, ele continua a leitura do `script` seguindo as próximas linhas, assim em diante?

Comment: Muito boa sua dúvida, vou pesquisar, fiquei bastante interessado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso se dá porque o interpretador primeiro analisa o código e depois executa. Ao analisar o código, ele irá carregar as funções na memória e então na fase de execução irá executar linha por linha. Como as funções já foram carregadas, não haverá problema em chamá-las antes da sua declaração.

**[Da documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.user-defined.php)**:

> As funções não precisam ser criadas antes de serem referenciadas,
>   exceto quando uma função é condicionalmente definida como mostrado nos
>   dois exemplos abaixo.
>
> Quando uma função é definida condicionalmente como nos dois exemplos
>   abaixo, sua definição precisa ser processada antes de ser chamada.

É um processo semelhante ao que ocorre no hoisting do JavaScript, onde funções são movidas ao topo do escopo antes do código ser executado:

```js
    teste();
    function teste(){
       console.log("ok");
    }
    // imprime no console: ok
```

Mas isso também só funciona no código do mesmo arquivo. Se você usar um include com a função e chamá-la antes, irá resultar em `Fatal error: Call to undefined function`.

Comment: "Quando uma função é definida condicionalmente como nos dois exemplos abaixo, sua definição precisa ser processada antes de ser chamada." Então se tenho uma função dentro de uma condição (ex.: ìf`), aí sim preciso ter ela acima ? Porque ele varre todo o script, armazena as functions em "primeiro nível" ?

Comment: "Se você usar um include com a função e chamá-la antes, irá resultar em Fatal error: Call to undefined function" Muito interessante. Apesar de praticamente nunca dar includes de bibliotecas depois de qualquer script, nunca tinha esbarrado nisso !

Comment: Isso mesmo. Conforme a documentação (veja os exemplos lá), se a função depender de uma condição, ela não pode ser chamada antes.

Comment: Fuja de definir funções condicionalmente, @RBZ. Em qualquer linguagem.

Comment: Muito interessante! Parabéns pela pergunta e pela resposta.